# Analytical solution of Laplace's equation with robin/third boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm new to PDE solution, and feel difficult to solve the Laplace's equation with robin boundary conditions.
The equation $\Delta u=0$ with boundary conditions shown in the picture:
[picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMaZK.jpg).

Does this problem has an analytical solution? if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separation of variables $u = X(x)Y(y)$, we obtain the ODEs

\begin{align}
X'' &= -\lambda X \\
Y'' &= \lambda Y
\end{align}

where we used $-\lambda$ for our separation constant, with associated boundary conditions

\begin{align}
u(L,y) &= 0 \implies X(L) = 0 \\
u_{x}(0,y) &= 0 \implies X'(0) = 0 \\
u_{y}(x,0) - hu(x,0) &= 0 \implies Y'(0) - hY(0) = 0
\end{align}

Solving the ODE in $X$, we find non-trivial solutions only if $\lambda > 0$ which yields

$$X = A \cos \sqrt{\lambda} x + B \sin \sqrt{\lambda} x$$

Now

\begin{align}
X'(0) &= \sqrt{\lambda} B \\
&= 0 \\
\implies B &= 0 \quad \text{(why?)} \\
\therefore X(L) &= A \cos \sqrt{\lambda} L \\
&= 0 \\
\implies \sqrt{\lambda} L &= \frac{(2n + 1) \pi}{2}, \quad n \ge 0 \quad \text{($A \ne 0$ for non-trivial solutions)} \\
\implies \lambda &= \frac{(2n + 1)^{2} \pi^{2}}{4L^{2}}, \quad n \ge 0 \quad(*)
\end{align}

and hence

$$X_{n} = A \cos \left( \frac{(2n + 1) \pi x}{2L} \right)$$

Using the eigenvalue $(*)$ and solving the ODE in $Y$ yields

$$Y = \frac{1}{h} \cdot \frac{(2n + 1) \pi }{2L} \cosh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi y}{2L} \right) + \sinh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi y}{2L} \right)$$

and so the general solution is given by

$$u(x,y) = \sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} \cos \left( \frac{(2n + 1) \pi x}{2L} \right) \left[ \frac{1}{h} \cdot \frac{(2n + 1) \pi }{2L} \cosh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi y}{2L} \right) + \sinh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi y}{2L} \right)\right]$$

Applying the inhomogeneous condition, we find

\begin{align}
u(x,L) &= u_{0} \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} \cos \left( \frac{(2n + 1) \pi x}{2L} \right) \left[ \frac{1}{h} \cdot \frac{(2n + 1) \pi }{2L} \cosh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi}{2} \right) + \sinh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi}{2} \right)\right] \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} C_{n} \cos \left( \frac{(2n + 1) \pi x}{2L} \right)
\end{align}

where

$$C_{n} = A_{n} \left[ \frac{1}{h} \cdot \frac{(2n + 1) \pi }{2L} \cosh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi}{2} \right) + \sinh \left(\frac{(2n + 1) \pi}{2} \right)\right]$$

You can now solve for the coefficients $C_{n}$ using [orthogonality relations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html). Note that when doing the integrals, a change of variable might help.

Comment: Really appreciate your help!! I calculate this equation through Matlab and the value on the top boundary and right boundary are not correct especially near the point (L, L). cuz the top boundary with a value of u_0 while the right boundary with a value of 0, and the value on point (L, L) is not reasonable. 
I'm not sure whether my Matlab code or this problem is wrong?

Comment: I can't possibly know why your code is doing what it is. It could be because you have computed the coefficients incorrectly, because the MATLAB code is incorrect or because you are having numerical issues. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232287/laplace-equation-on-the-corners-and-boundary-of-a-rectangle) for a brief discussion about the corner issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have solved the problem now, it turned out I input the wrong variable.
Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Mattos, why did you delete your comment here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895737/

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The first step sets
$\ds{\mrm{u}_{x}\pars{x,y} = \sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0}}
\mrm{a}\pars{k,y}\sin\pars{kx}}$ which satisfies the boundary condition $\ds{\mrm{u}_{x}\pars{0,y} = 0}$. Then,
\begin{align}
&\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} = 
-\sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0}}
\mrm{a}\pars{k,y}{\cos\pars{kx} \over k} + \mrm{f}\pars{y}
\end{align}
The boundary condition $\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{L,y} = 0}$ is satisfied by choosing
$\ds{k \in \braces{k_{n}\ \mid\ k_{n} = \pars{2n + 1}{\pi \over 2L}\,,\
n = 1,2,3,\ldots}}$ and
$\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{y} = 0}$. The general solution becomes
$$
\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{y}{\cos\pars{k_{n}x} \over k_{n}}
$$
which must satisfies the Laplace differential equation. Namely,
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{\mrm{a}_{n}''\pars{y} -
k_{n}^{2}\,\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{y}}{\cos\pars{k_{n}x} \over k_{n}} = 0
$$
which leads to
$\ds{\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{y} = b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}y} +
c_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}y}}$ such that
$$
\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}y} +
c_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}y}}{\cos\pars{k_{n}x} \over k_{n}}
$$
One of the remaining boundary conditions
$\ds{\pars{~\mrm{u}\pars{x,L} = u_{0}~}}$ leads to
$$
u_{0} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}L} + c_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}L}}
{\cos\pars{k_{n}x} \over k_{n}}
$$
Multiply both members by $\ds{2\cos\pars{k_{n}x}/L}$ and integrate over $\ds{x \in\pars{0,L}}$:
\begin{align}
&u_{0}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{L}{2\cos\pars{k_{n}x} \over L}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{{4 \over \pi}\,{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2n + 1}}}\ =\
{b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}L} + c_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}L} \over k_{n}}
\\[2mm] &\ \implies
\bbx{b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}L} + c_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}L} = 
{2\pars{-1}^{n} \over L}\,u_{0}} \label{1}\tag{1}
\\ &
\end{align}
The last boundary condition
$\ds{\pars{~\mrm{u}_{y}\pars{x,0} = h\,\mrm{u}\pars{x,0}~}}$
yields
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
b_{n}\cos\pars{k_{n}x} =
h\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
c_{n}{\cos\pars{k_{n}x} \over k_{n}}
\\[2mm] \implies &\
\bbx{k_{n}b_{n} - h\, c_{n} = 0} \label{2}\tag{2} \\ &
\end{align}
(\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) yield:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{b_{n}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\pars{-1}^{n}\,{h \over k_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}L} +
h\sinh\pars{k_{n}L}}\,{2u_{0} \over L}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{c_{n}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\pars{-1}^{n}\,{k_{n} \over k_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}L} +
h\sinh\pars{k_{n}L}}\,{2u_{0} \over L}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and
\begin{align}
&\mbox{}
\\ 
&\mrm{u}\pars{x,y}
\\ = &\ \bbx{{2u_{0} \over L}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{h\sinh\pars{k_{n}y} + k_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}y} \over
k_{n}\cosh\pars{k_{n}L} +
h\sinh\pars{k_{n}L}}
{\cos\pars{k_{n}x} \over k_{n}}}
\\ & \bbx{\mbox{with}\ k_{n} = \pars{2n +1}\,{\pi \over 2L}}
\\ &
\end{align}